# getting warnings after installing geoposition app

Tags: python, django, django-models

When I am running my project, I get this type of warnings

**RemovedInDjango110Warning: SubfieldBase has been deprecated. Use Field.from_db_value instead**

here's code

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models
from django.utils.six import with_metaclass
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils.encoding import smart_text

from . import Geoposition
from .forms import GeopositionField as GeopositionFormField


class GeopositionField(with_metaclass(models.SubfieldBase, models.Field)):
    description = _("A geoposition (latitude and longitude)")

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['max_length'] = 42
        super(GeopositionField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_internal_type(self):
        return 'CharField'

    def to_python(self, value):
        if not value or value == 'None':
            return None
        if isinstance(value, Geoposition):
            return value
        if isinstance(value, list):
            return Geoposition(value[0], value[1])

        # default case is string
        value_parts = value.rsplit(',')
        try:
            latitude = value_parts[0]
        except IndexError:
            latitude = '0.0'
        try:
            longitude = value_parts[1]
        except IndexError:
            longitude = '0.0'

        return Geoposition(latitude, longitude)

    def get_prep_value(self, value):
        return str(value)

    def value_to_string(self, obj):
        value = self._get_val_from_obj(obj)
        return smart_text(value)

    def formfield(self, **kwargs):
        defaults = {
            'form_class': GeopositionFormField
        }
        defaults.update(kwargs)
        return super(GeopositionField, self).formfield(**defaults)
```

What should I do in this code for removing this warning

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's very clear. `models.SubfieldBase` has been depreciated. You can see this in the [Django release docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/releases/1.8/#subfieldbase)

> django.db.models.fields.subclassing.SubfieldBase has been deprecated and will be removed in Django 1.10. Historically, it was used to handle fields where type conversion was needed when loading from the database, but it was not used in .values() calls or in aggregates. It has been replaced with from_db_value(). Note that the new approach does not call the to_python() method on assignment as was the case with SubfieldBase.

You need to either remove `models.SubfieldBase` and if needs be add a [`from_db_value`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.from_db_value) method to your field to translate from the DB value to the python value.